# Azure AD: Send welcome email when user is assigned to the application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I would like to send a welcome email to the user when the Azure AD admin assigns the user to the application (enterprise or custom). It would be nice to use a custom template to define an access URL and maybe some additional info (how to use, some rules, etc.). I haven't found anything similar in the Azure portal.

Does Azure AD provide such functionality? Or should I build custom implementation (Graph API, EventGrid + Azure Functions, SCIM protocol, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, at the very base, you want an email to be sent whenever a user is assigned to an enterprise application (or custom - assuming that also falls under same). I assume you do not need to know much about who actually assigned the permissions. Either way, with the query below you should have enough to get going.

As far as I know there's no native support for this in AD (I couldn't find anything at all that's available but I could be wrong) but a workaround for us was to do it using Log Analytics + Azure Logic App. While our use case is slightly different (we use it to monitor and be alerted for logins to a specific account), the same logic might apply to you - I put together a few lines to query log analytics. <s>but I couldn't get the alert part working - Azure could just be sleepy right now.</s>

EDIT: Alert worked the following day. Just needed some time to warm up I guess.

Give it a try:

1. Make sure Azure AD has diagnostic settings configured to send logs to a Log Workspace
2. Query the workspace using the following:

```
AuditLogs
| where TimeGenerated > ago(5m) //Change as required
| where ActivityDisplayName has "Add app role assignment grant to user"
| project Time = TimeGenerated, Activity = ActivityDisplayName, Application=parse_json(TargetResources)[0].displayName, User=parse_json(TargetResources)[1].userPrincipalName
| where Application contains "myapp"
```

3. [Create an alert from Log Analytics](https://dirteam.com/sander/2020/07/22/howto-set-an-alert-to-notify-when-an-additional-person-is-assigned-the-azure-ad-global-administrator-role/) (hopefully you get it working right away - each alert cost USD 1.50/month).

   (a) You will need to create an `Action Group`

   (b) Under `Action Group`, configure your email in the `Notifications`.

   (c) You will need to come back to reconfigure an `Action` field to the Logic App you will create below.
4. Create a Logic App and start with an [HTTP connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http) as the trigger to receive the content in JSON format.
5. Setup a [Send an Email (v2)](https://blog.sandro-pereira.com/2020/01/26/logic-apps-how-to-send-a-well-formatted-html-email-notification-with-office-365-outlook-connector/) action with all variables and such, or another connector if applicable in your case. Customise the email in HTML

One alternative to using Log Analytics and Alerts could also be to [use PowerShell to query AAD logs](https://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/powershell/8132/searching-active-directory-logs-with-powershell/) and then parse the information to Logic App through the `HTTP POST Url` that shows up when you save the HTTP Connector.

Another alternative to using the HTTP Connector could be to use the [O365 connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/#:%7E:text=The%20When%20a%20new%20email,could%20be%20rare%20circumstances%20when) with trigger `When a new email arrives (v3)`

Things to consider:

1. There's at least a 5 minutes delay between the time the event is logged and triggered. [This is just the way the alert query works.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/data-ingestion-time)
2. You will need to login to Logic App using the mailbox from which you want to send that email. That's something you might want to manage separately - expiring credentials etc.

Hope this gives you some ideas.